# php display current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to display the current page that  user is on and will update everytime the user goes to a different page. Here is my code so far;

```
$files = [
'<a href="session.php">'. 'Home' .'</a>' ,
'<a href="sql1.php">'. 'SQL1' .'</a>' ,
'<a href="sql2.php">'. 'SQL2' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql3.php">'. 'SQL3' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql4.php">'. 'SQL4' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql5_1.php">'. 'SQL5_1' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql5_2.php">'. 'SQL5_2' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql6.php">'. 'SQL6' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql7.php">'. 'SQL7' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql8.php">'. 'SQL8' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql9.php">'. 'SQL9' .'</a>',
'<a href="sql10.php">'. 'SQL10' .'</a>',
];

file_get_contents('sql1.php');
file_get_contents('sql2.php');
file_get_contents('sql3.php');
file_get_contents('sql4.php');
file_get_contents('sql5_1.php');
file_get_contents('sql5_2.php');
file_get_contents('sql6.php');
file_get_contents('sql7.php');
file_get_contents('sql8.php');
file_get_contents('sql9.php');
file_get_contents('sql10.php');


echo "Next Page ".$files[array_rand($files)];
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to use the magic constant '__FILE__' just show it shows the file alone and not the file path?

Answer (score 1):

php has a [Magic constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for this, `__FILE__`. This will return the path to the current file and its file name.

```
// Path and file
echo "Current page: " . __FILE__;

// Get only the filename
$split = preg_split('/\//', __FILE__);
echo $split[count($split) - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks I'm getting somewhere! Is there anyway I can just have the file name without the full file path?

Comment: Yes you can, by getting the last part of the `__FILE__` value. I updated my answer with an example by splitting the string on `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solution solved your problem, consider marking it as the answer to your question. This way other people might find this solution. :)